# How can I reattach an HVAC duct that came loose below the floor?

Tags: ducts

I just moved into a new house and found that couple of floor ducts have fallen off in the space below. They were screwed from below to keep it in place and I am not sure how to fix it back again to my floor. Can someone please help me with this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to these ducts from your basement/crawlspace?

Comment: no i dont. I wound want to try fixing it from above somehow without cutting through cieling or floors. Just moved into a new house and cant really afford to spend a lot

Comment: I see, see my answer

Comment: I don't think those were mounted correctly.  Shouldn't the flange be **on top of the floor** (under the carpet)?   Perhaps you can force the flange up through the hole.  If you destroy it, pull the hose all the way up, attach a new flange drop it down.  Perhaps they took a short cut because of the carpet..

Comment: @SteveWellens If the carpet installer did their job before the HVAC was installed then the installer just took the path of least resistance unfortunately. OP would risk ripping the carpet to do things properly at this point and if it were to sit on top of the carpet then the flange would need to be trimmed so that it's hidden by the register.

Comment: Just wondering if flange was on top of floor wouldnt it make the carpet floor uneven. I am very new to all this so I am not sure of it

Comment: `I just moved into a new house` Do you mean a *new* house, or a house that's new *to you*?  New houses come with warranties, usually, and this is pretty obviously an installation fail.

Comment: The house is new to me...

Answer (score 8):

The tiny screws have obviously failed so you'll need to re-fasten the flange to the subfloor.

It looks like a 6 inch duct so if you can reach the duct with your hand then do this:

**Permanent fix**

- Bring the duct back up to the hole
- Drill a hole through your floor and through the flange around the duct

  - Make sure these holes will be covered by the register
  - 2 holes at minimum; one at opposing ends of the flange. You want 4? Go for it!
  - The holes need to be big enough for a toggle bolt. The toggle bolt instructions should advise on a hole size
- Insert a toggle bolt through the hole and tighten it until it holds properly

  - Toggle bolts are usually pretty long so you may wish to shop around for shorter ones or carefully hacksaw the longer ones
  - If your hole is too big and the head of the bolt falls through the floor then you can remove the v-wing, add a washer, replace the v-wing, and try again. Or drill a new hole of course =)
- Put your register back in place and enjoy your heating/cooling

[image]

**Temporary fix as requested in the comments**

Instead of toggle bolts you could:

- Buy some all-purpose construction adhesive such as [Loctite-Power-Grab-Express](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Loctite-Power-Grab-Express-9-fl-oz-All-Purpose-Construction-Adhesive-2022554/206432092)
- Apply it to the flange
- Bring the duct up to the floor hole
- Drill regular screws through the floor and into the flange
- Put your register back in place and convince (lie to) yourself that you will return at some point to do this properly with toggle bolts =)

---

Since you have to go to the store to buy the construction adhesive anyways then why not just buy the toggle bolts and drill bit instead? It will take the same amount of time and you'll know it's done properly.

Comment: I mentioned in a comment on my answer but thought I'd put here as well; if you can pull up/fold back the carpet around the hole and put the bolts through and then replace the carpet on top, the bolts won't be visible.

Comment: @FredricShope I think OP wishes to avoid further damage and pulling up the carpet might tear it and create a new problem. Floor registers will generally have a 1 inch lip all around so the bolt heads should never be seen if they drill the holes close to the duct hole on the flange.

Comment: the lip i guess does not cover the width of the floow so it will remain below the floor

Comment: @wickedvishu Yes, my answer is for keeping the flange below the subfloor; just like it was previously installed. If you could update your picture to show the register next to the floor hole then it would be helpful.

Comment: Is there a good adhesive I can use for time being to reattach it before i can drill and screw it back in. Can you suggest a good adhesive that works well with plastic as well as wood

Comment: @wickedvishu All-purpose construction adhesive such as [Loctite-Power-Grab-Express](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Loctite-Power-Grab-Express-9-fl-oz-All-Purpose-Construction-Adhesive-2022554/206432092) would probably work fine. It claims to hold material immediately but you may wish to apply pressure for a minute or two since the weight of the ductwork may cause it to separate. You may also wish to drive in two or more regular screws from the top to make sure everything holds together while the product cures.

Comment: Addedd a picture for register

Comment: @wickedvishu I see. I still recommend my answer as it is written. The previous installer didn't install it properly most likely because the carpet was already in their way and they would rather not rip the carpet. If you every get your carpet replaced then you may wish to take that opportunity to bring the flange on top of the subfloor but the hassle probably won't be worth it once you install toggle bolts.

Comment: Thanks!! i will try using toggle bolts.. can i use platic ones as they can work with small screws. I am just wondering if flange is installed from top.. wouldnt it cause the carpet to be uneven.. Sorry i am very new to all this so dont really understand a lot

Comment: @wickedvishu The flange (that rectangle surrounding the round duct) looks to be fairly thin. When carpet is installed there is usually some sort of padding that gets laid down first. So if you have subfloor, flange, padding, then carpet then I don't think you would notice any unevenness with your carpet. Since the flange is larger than the register you could opt to cut the flange into a circle. This way if there was a bulge then it's hidden by the presence of the register.

Comment: @wickedvishu Like I said though, if you use a toggle bolt then you really don't have to worry about the issue at all.

Comment: @wickedvishu Plastic toggle bolts tend to break in my experience so you might end up breaking a few before getting it right.

Answer (score 2):

I would first try long pliers to grab and pull the vent cowl up to the hole, and a strong construction adhesive like PowerGrab around the flange to hold it to the bottom of the floor, and a clamp to keep it in place while the adhesive dries.

Example long pliers:

[image]

However, the best fix would involve access from below by cutting the ceiling and reinstalling screws through the flange into the floor, and that's what I'd fall back to if the "easy fix" doesn't work or fails sometime later.

Comment: I can reach out to grab it by hand and can bring it in place... just wondering how i can make it stay there from above. Just moved into a new house and cant afford to spend on cutting through ceiling or floor to fix it. Is there any clamp or screw which can be ysed to fix it from above

Comment: Adhesive, or screws. (MonkeyZeus has a good answer with toggle bolts from above) Adhesive has the benefit of not being visible from above, but that carpet can obscure smaller screw heads and if you pull up the carpet and put flat head screws/bolts down and then replace the carpet, will be nearly invisible also.

Comment: Can you suggest a good adhesive that can hold on this to the wooden floor. I mean that works good for both plastic and the wood

Answer (score 0):

Pull the pipe up to the hole by hand. Adding some construction adhesive can help hold it in place while you screw.

Put screws at an angle from the inside edge of the pipe to the subfloor:

[image: Illustration of screwing angle]

The screws will be invisible once you put the cover on, and because of the angle they should hold better than ones screwed straight through the subfloor to the thin plastic.